# Creating a circle button and centering text in compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a circle button with text of some initials inside that should be centered. The button size should be `34.dp` and the text should be `13.sp` but I have to increase the size of the button to get the text to display correctly

I think the reason the text doesn't display is because of the internal padding of the Text composable.

```
Button(
    modifier = Modifier.size(49.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = Color.Black,
        contentColor = Color.White),
    onClick = {

    }) {
    Text(text = "JB",
        fontSize = 13.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        style = TextStyle(
            lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
                trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.Both
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default content padding `contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)`

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
onClick = {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
},
modifier = Modifier.width(34.dp),
contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = "JB",
        fontSize = 13.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to apply a `contentPadding` of `0.dp` if you want to use `34.dp` as size

```
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
        shape = CircleShape,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        //...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please add shape properties to Button as below and also add content padding as 0 as well.

```
 Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier= Modifier.size(34.dp),  
        shape = CircleShape,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),  
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(contentColor =  Color.White)
    ) {
        Text(text = "JB",
            fontSize = 13.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            style = TextStyle(
                lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                    alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
                    trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.Both
                )
            )
        )
    }
```